# opencv em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, rgb

Necessito fazer um algoritmo que lê o código da cor e abre uma janela com a cor.

Sei que preciso usar a biblioteca *cv*, mas não sei como faz isso e não acho nada parecido na internet

Alguém sabe como ajudar?

Comment: Veja se [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/337026/75104) ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import messagebox
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("sample.jpg")
color = int(image[300, 300])

messagebox.showinfo("Cor em BGR",  color)
```